# How did Klaang ended up on Earth?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-enterprise

From where Klaang was travelling when he crash-landed on Earth or where exactly Rigel Ten is?

If I'm not missing something essential then in "Broken Bow" it is said that:

- Klaang was traveling from *somewhere* to Kronos, through Rigel Ten and crashed on Earth,
- Archer's team was traveling from Earth, through Rigel Ten, to Kronos.

First assumptions says that Earth is somewhere between Rigel Ten and Kronos (because Klaang left Rigel Ten on his journey to Kronos and hit Earth) while second assumption says otherwise -- that Rigel Ten is somewhere between Earth and Kronos (because Archer left Earth on his way to Kronos and hit Rigel Ten).

What am I missing?

Comment: tenth planet of the star Rigel presumably

Comment: Maybe Klaang didn't want to travel in a straight line to shake off Sulaban pursuers.

Comment: Maybe, or maybe one remembers that planets are in motion with respect to each other. I do not think that this issue has been addressed at all.

Comment: @EdmundDantes Neither planets within a star system nor stars within the galaxy move at a rate that would appreciably change distances in the length of time the episode takes place.

Comment: Qo'nos, not Kronos.

Comment: @Tim - Kronos is easier to spell correctly than Qo'noS.

Comment: @Tim and Jasen: I'm citing directly what I've heard in my version (if there are any others?) of this episode. So, "Rigel Ten", not "Rigel X" and not "Tenth planed of the Rigel system" and "Kronos" not "Qo'noS". I was also surprised, because I recall the other name from Deep Space 9.

Comment: Qo'nos is the correct spelling, Kronos is the English pronunciation.

Comment: @Tim - There is no lowercase "s" in the Klingon language.  To spell "Qo'noS" correctly, you need to use a capital "S".  In your objections to the Anglicized version, you've been incorrectly spelling it in Klingon as "Qo'nos".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Klaang went around 35LY in the **wrong direction**, presumably in an unsuccessful attempt to shake off his pursuers by mingling with shipping traffic and transport ships coming and going from Earth.

[image]
<sub><sup>[Star Trek: Star Charts](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_Star_Charts)</sup></sub>